# Integrate WSO2 APIM190 with DAS300

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Since I already know APIM 1.9.0 is default support BAM, that UI is for deploy the BAM analytics artifacts called toolbox. When you work with DAS, you should leave Data Analyzer Configurations as blank. And need to deploy artifacts(CaPP) manually on DAS .

I seached and found below link which might be helpful:
http://blog.rukspot.com/2015/09/publishing-apim-runtime-statistics-to.html

But the bad thing is for unknown reason I tried times to access this link ,,all failed.

Can anybody help to paste the content of above link here or just send a private mail to me  via my mail :  menglong567@aliyun.com

That would be very appreaciated !

Answer (score 0):

Please find the official documentation for WSO2 API-M 1.9.0 statistics configurations in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics).

All the necessary information is covered in the official doc.